# How can I download XCode from my Windows XP PC?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer, xcode

I am at work now and cannot access the internet from my MacBook. I'm trying to download a new installation of XCode from Windows, then transfer it over and install it on my MacBook. When I try to download from my XP computer (IE8 and FF3.6), it says download complete, but the file size is 0 bytes.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently downloaded Xcode on my Windows 7 machine. There should be nothing preventing you simply downloading the file, no matter the operating system it supports. The file is 2.4GB. Is there something about your work network (proxy?) that is preventing you from downloading a big file.

Don't IE8 and FF create a dummy file of 0kb in your download directory but save the file into a temporary directory until the file is complete?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a proxy here at work, but I have it configured. And I clicked Save to Desktop, so it shouldn't be going to a temp directory. I actually just tethered my iPhone and downloaded directly to my Mac....a 4 hour download lol